# Slicing a Dask Dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, dask

I have the following code where I like to do a train/test split on a Dask dataframe

```
df = dd.read_csv(csv_filename, sep=',', encoding="latin-1",
                     names=cols, header=0, dtype='str')
```

But when I try to do slices like

```
for train, test in cv.split(X, y):
    df.fit(X[train], y[train])
```

it fails with the error

```
KeyError: '[11639 11641 11642 ..., 34997 34998 34999] not in index'
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Check if [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54507584/812102) helps.

Answer (score 7):

Dask.dataframe doesn't support row-wise slicing.  It does support the `loc` operation if you have a sensible index.

However in your case of train/test splitting you will probably be better served by the [random_split](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html#dask.dataframe.DataFrame.random_split) method.

```
train, test = df.random_split([0.80, 0.20])
```

You could also make many splits and concat in different ways

```
splits = df.random_split([0.20, 0.20, 0.20, 0.20, 0.20])

for i in range(5):
    trains = [splits[j] for j in range(5) if j != i]
    train = dd.concat(trains, axis=0)
    test = splits[i]
```

Comment: So basically I cannot do StratifiedKFold CV on a Dask dataframe?

Comment: You can't slice with normal means, but that doesn't mean that you can't do what you want.  Note that `random_split` can accept a list of arbitrary size of fractions.

Comment: Any code sample for how can I achieve CV with this?

Comment: I've added a slightly longer example that should help you along

Comment: train = dd.concat(trains, axis=0) returns me 5 partitions instead of 1, when I do train['columnName'] similarly test['columnName'] also returns me 5 partitions of varying length

what to do here?