# Slicing out a few rows from a `dask.DataFrame`

Tags: dask

Often, when working with a large `dask.DataFrame`, it would be useful to grab only a few rows on which to test all subsequent operations.

Currently, according to [Slicing a Dask Dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44475492/slicing-a-dask-dataframe), this is unsupported.

- I was hoping to then use `head` to achieve the same (since that command is supported), but that returns a regular pandas DataFrame.
- I also tried `df[:1000]`, which executes, but generates an output different from that you'd expect from Pandas.

Is there any way to grab the first 1000 rows from a `dask.DataFrame`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If your dataframe has a [sensibly partitioned index](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/dataframe-design.html#partitions) then I recommend using `.loc`

```
small = big.loc['2000':'2005']
```

If you want to maintain the same number of partitions, you might consider sample

```
small = big.sample(frac=0.01)
```

If you just want a single partition, you might try `get_partition`

```
small = big.get_partition(0)
```

You can also, always use `to_delayed` and `from_delayed` to build your own custom solution.  http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/dataframe-create.html#dask-delayed

More generally, Dask.dataframe doesn't keep row-counts per partition, so the specific question of "give me 1000 rows" ends up being surprisingly hard to answer.  It's a lot easier to answer questions like "give me all the data in January" or "give me the first partition"

Comment: Thanks, grabbing the partition is good enough for my purpose.  Any comment on whether `df[:1000]` does the right thing or not, compared to Pandas?

Comment: Pandas devs would recommend not using `df[:1000]` and using `.loc` or `.iloc` explicitly. You probably were referring to `.iloc` which is not supported in dask.dataframe.

Comment: This behavior is described both in the docs (http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#slicing-ranges) and is mentioned by Wes on at least one S/O answer.  So I suspect that silently doing something else than Pandas here is going to trip users up.

Answer (score 3):

You may repartition your initial DataFrame into an arbitrary number of partitions.  If you want slices of 1000 rows :

```
npart = round(len(df)/1000)
parted_df = df.repartition(npartitions=npart)
```

Then just call the partition you wish :

```
first_1000_rows = parted_df.partitions[0]
```

Note that unless the number of rows in your initial DataFrame is a multiple of 1000, you won't get *exactly* 1000 rows.